# Dynamically check extensions from string in Reactive Extensions

Tags: string, rxjs

I have string with accepted file's extensions. Something like "JPG,PNG,TXT". String can be whatever I want. I am using Reactive Extensions, so i filter files by using Where(). For now i am using

```
Where(e => e.FullPath.Contains(filtering)
```

But it only works, when there is only 1 extension. Any idea how to make it dynamically? Where will be call only once! I write in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a LINQ question rather than javascript(rxjs).  However, as LINQ seems to be comparable with array methods in js I shall attempt to answer.

First convert the string of extensions into an array.  This only needs to be done once:

```
filterExtensions = filtering.Split(',');
```

Then the condition would be:

```
Where(e => filterExtensions.Any(
  extension => e.FullPath.Contains(extension)
))
```